# Static & Media files 404 behind NGINX proxy pass

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have what I believe to be a slightly convoluted Django/Gunicorn/NGINX stack that is giving me trouble as I try to migrate it from the django development server to a production setup with Gunicorn and NGINX.  Specifically, I'm having trouble serving static files.

SYSTEM ARCHITECTURE: I have one physical server with a public IP address.  This physical server hosts 3 VM's on a private virtual network (NAT).  Each VM run's it's own django project on port 8001.  I forward port 8001 on each VM to unique available ports on the physical machine.  So, in summary, the architecture looks like the following:

PRIVATE VIRTUAL NETWORK VM's:

- VM1 runs "site 1" on VM1 port 8001
- VM2 runs "site 2" on VM2 port 8001
- VM3 runs "site 3" on VM3 port 8001

HOST SERVER:

- Publishes "site 1" on host port 8001 (VM port 8001 fwd.to Host port 8001)
- Publishes "site 2" on host port 8002 (VM port 8001 fwd.to Host port 8002)
- Publishes "site 3" on host port 8003 (VM port 8001 fwd.to Host port 8003)

This works really well for development with the django development server.  I just need to include a port # in the URL.  As in:

- myserver.edu:8001 for site 1
- myserver.edu:8002 for site 2
- myserver.edu:8003 for site 3

For production I would like to setup NGINX to serve the sites as:

- myserver.edu/site1 for site 1
- myserver.edu/site2 for site 2
- myserver.edu/site3 for site 3

I installed NGINX on the host machine and configured it to use TLS.  The NGINX configuration on the host machine defines 3 locations below with following config.  You can see that I use the proxy_pass to route traffic for each site to the Virtual Network on the host machine.

```
location /site1/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.122.243:8001/;
}

location /site2/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.122.244:8001/;
}

location /site3/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.122.245:8001/;
}
```

So any request for:

- List item

myserver.edu/site1 goes to port 8001 on VM1

- List item

myserver.edu/site2 goes to port 8001 on VM2

- List item

myserver.edu/site3 goes to port 8001 on VM3

On VM1 I have a django site + gunicorn + NGINX with the following config (same setup on all VMs):

```
server {
   listen 8001;
   server_name 0.0.0.0;

   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   location /static/ {
        root /home/rcrv/bubbles/s2uds_user/gui;
   }

   location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/rcrv/bubbles/s2uds_user/bubs.sock;
   }

}
```

My Site 1 root URL from urls.py is this:  url(r'^$', gv.home),

BEHAVIOR UNDER THE ABOVE NGINX PRODUCTION CONFIG:

If I browse site 1 on VM1 from within the NAT with a URL such as:
  192.168.122.243:8001/

- This will work perfectly - Static and media file are served

If I browse from public IP space with a URL such as:
  myerver.edu/site1/

- This will render all dynamic content from django but will fail to serve static content (with a 404).  My browser developer console shows that the browser is looking for the static content at https://myserver.com/static
- Note that I expected it to look for static content at myserver/site1/static

If I modify that URL directly in the browser to be myserver.com/site1/static I can access the static content that was missing

ATTEMPTS TO MITIGATE/FIX INCLUDE:

I changed the location block on the NGINX config of the VM to be:
location = /site1/static/
No luck.

Debugging shows that the browser is still trying to find the static content at:  myserver.edu/static

QUESTION:
How the heck do I modify or fix the configuration such that django includes that "/site1/" part in the static URL?  I'm inclined to think that this problem is not an NGINX config issue but instead a django problem.  Rather, I believe I need to tell django to prepend /site1/ to it's static URL.

Ideas?  I've read numerous responses to similar django static file issues but yet on that fixes this.

Thank you.

UPDATE:  I've started to figure this out.  Here is what worked for me.

1. I created a /static/ directory at /var/www/static on each VM and set the STATIC_ROOT in the settings.py file to be this location, then ran collect static to copy all static content to this directory.
2. I then modified static file location block within the NGINX conf on the VM to be:

```
location /static/ {
        root /var/www/;
   }
```

3. Finally I modified the STATIC_URL in settings.py from: STATIC_URL = /static/ to STATIC_URL = /site1/static/

The result is the static content is now served in production under NGINX.  The cause was my incomplete understanding of static content methods in general.  Typing out the question here sort of clarified the problem and led me to the solution.  Hopes this helps someone with a similar architecture.  Now to fix the media files - likely the same approach.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer if you think it is helpful.